# Cannot find item name C# XML

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem with my XML document.

I want my program to find all values of the items in my XML file, but only if the handlingType is of a certain character bunch.

Code (C#) :

```
string path = "//files//handling.meta";

             var doc = XDocument.Load(path);

            var items = doc.Descendants("HandlingData").Elements("Item");

            var query = from i in items

                        select new
                         {
                             HandlingName = (string)i.Element("handlingName"),
                             HandlingType = (string)i.Element("HandlingType"),
                             Mass = (decimal?)i.Element("fMass")
                         };
            foreach (var HandlingType in items)
            {
                if (HandlingType.ToString() == "HANDLING_TYPE_FLYING")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(HandlingType.ToString());
                }
            }
```

The above code demonstraights a short version of what I want to happen, but fails to find this handlingType (does not show the messageBox)

Here's the XML :

```
<CHandlingDataMgr>
    <HandlingData>
        <Item type="CHandlingData">
            <handlingName>Plane</handlingName>
            <fMass value="380000.000000"/>
            <handlingType>HANDLING_TYPE_FLYING</handlingType>
        </Item>
        <Item type="CHandlingData">
            <handlingName>Car1</handlingName>
            <fMass value="150000.000000"/>
            <handlingType>HANDLING_TYPE_DRIVING</handlingType>
        </Item>
    </HandlingData>
</CHandlingDataMgr>
```

I would like the output to show the handlingName if it contains a certain HandlingType
For e.g.

```
if (handlingType == "HANDLING_TYPE_FLYING") 
{
    messageBox.Show(this.HandlingName);
}
```

My problem in short : Program does not find item's handling type, it does find the tag but when asked to display, returns empty/shows as nothing.

Edit: Also in the XML handling_type_flying contains extra elements such as thrust that cannot be found in each item (such as car), I would like the program to also find these elements. (this is a second problem I'm facing, maybe should ask 2nd ques?)

Comment: Print `HandlingType.ToString()` and you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: Returns: Input string was in incorrect format, is this because of '_' used? If so, how could I edit the code to see these characters?

Comment: When Printing it it shouldn't be an inputstring.

Comment: I have tried removing the ' (string) ' before element declaring, but this still returns incorrect format error. I'm unable to edit the XML, because this would cause all sorts of problems in the project

Comment: Everything can do `.ToString()`.

Comment: Yes, and it does, the API loads & error list shows none until button click event, that returns error : Input string was not in a correct format. (Handling type), HandlingName loads fine for all items

Comment: your "Input string was not in a correct format." ierror is simply caused by Mass = (decimal?)i.Element("fMass"). You are trying to convert an Element , with no innards, into a value. As I stated in my answer you need to use Mass = i.Element("fMass").Attribute("value").Value

Comment: You're right, just for testing purposes I then removed that element & ran the code again, now it returns no errors, but also shows no messagebox. Edit: Just copied all code & again, it shows no errors, shows no message box (Api doesn't stop working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things that need fixing.

1. you are not using your query in your foreach loop.  `foreach (var item in query)`
2. Your element has an upercase "H" but should be lowercase "handlingType".  `HandlingType = (string)i.Element("handlingType"),`
3. You are not pulling the Attribute value of your fMass element.`Mass = i.Element("fMass").Attribute("value").Value`
4. Once you adjust your Query in your foreach loop you then need to adjust the loop to account for looping over your newly made object.
5. NOTE that I removed **(decimal)** from **Mass =** **i.Element("fMass").Attribute("value").Value**

here is the code with all the fixes.

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string path = "//files//handling.meta";
            var doc = XDocument.Load(path);

            var items = doc.Descendants("HandlingData").Elements("Item");

            var query = from i in items

                        select new
                        {
                            HandlingName = (string)i.Element("handlingName"),
                            HandlingType = (string)i.Element("handlingType"),
                            Mass = i.Element("fMass").Attribute("value").Value
                        };
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                if (item.HandlingType == "HANDLING_TYPE_FLYING")
                {
                    //Remove messagebox if consoleapp
                    MessageBox.Show(item.HandlingType);
                    MessageBox.Show(item.HandlingName);
                    Console.WriteLine(item.HandlingType);
                    Console.WriteLine(item.HandlingName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**I would recommend looking into serializing your xml to an object.**

Comment: Shows fine in my console app. If you copied my code line by line then you may have ended up with a "Console.WriteLine" instead of a MessageBox. If still does not show then please put a break point in the four each loop and see what properties in your item are being populated.

Comment: I guess, HandlingName is needed to print, as per original question.

Comment: @Arindam Nayak : Right but he claimed the problem was due to not finding the handling type. Which my solution shows the problems in why the type was not resolving. Still...decided to edit it in to be SUPER clear. :)

Comment: Error: Input string was not in a correct format. Using WinForm API, have also tried .ToString() method, same error both times =-(

Comment: most likely because you still have the (decimal) in Mass = i.Element("fMass").Attribute("value").Value. Which my code does not. Remove it and it will work fine. Please copy the working code I gave you into a new console application and compare the differences if you get future problems.

Comment: Ah, dude I'm real sorry for wasting your time. My problem was caused by 'SubHandlingData', a second section within the handlingName that I did not see. Thanks for your help, I would not of found this section without your note : "there is information being left out", the XML doc is very large you see. Thanks problem solved =D

Comment: No problem. Please mark it as the answer as it answers the question provided :)

Comment: +1 for `I would recommend looking into serializing your xml to an object.` - this makes things so much easier

Answer (score 0):

If you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx  the ToString() method doesn't return the name of the tag, but the indented XML.

You should instead be using the Value property. Also you should use .equals("...") instead of ==

```
if (handlingType.Value.equals("HANDLING_TYPE_FLYING")
{
    messageBox.Show(this.handlingname);
}
```